# Killing an app on a jailbroken iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am currently trying to build an app that will kill other apps on my jailbroken iPhone. I would like my app to be able to kill apps even when my app is in the background. I only have one problem though I can not find a kill command to do this. I am a newer programmer so as many details as you can give would be appreciated.
Thank You

Comment: Why not just kill them manually?

Comment: The reason I am not trying to kill them manually is because I am doing this for a school project and I said that I would have my app kill another app on my phone so I can not just kill them manually.

Comment: Why not make a legitimate application? There are plenty of easy ones to do.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way (untested, but should work):

```
system("killall \"NAME-OF-EXECUTABLE\"");
```

Generally speaking, however, I would recommend using a branch of the `exec` functions instead of `system` to perform this task.